# Update/import image with user input

Tags: vba, excel

I want the user to simply, with a button, select a picture from his or hers computer without having to resize or move it.
Instead of the path maybe an "import image dialog" or what it´s called.
The picture size ratio should be locked but still fit the page in width.

I´ve tried to modify this whithout any progress.

`ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 1")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture "C:\..."
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
        .RotateWithObject = msoTrue
    End With`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub OpenImg()
    Dim strFile
    strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Selct an image", FileFilter:="Picture Files (*.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp),*.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp", MultiSelect:=False)
    If strFile = False Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Meh!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFile).Select
        With Selection.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = ThisWorkbook.Application.Width - 75
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a separate question and frankly you are asking SO to write code for you. Can you show what exactly you have tried to achieve this?